# spring-cloud-stream kafka how to produce message with round robin strategy?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We have upgrade **spring boot to 2.0.3** Release (previously **1.5.10**).
Due to that, we have changed the release of kafka & spring-cloud-stream (**2.0.0-Release**)
In our property YML file we dont always configure `partitionKeyExpression` and most of our `partitionCount` is greater than 1.
In previous release, these settings along with not passing any key would lead to produce messages in round robin strategy.
In new release, same settings leads to method `isPartitioned` to return true, which adds Interceptor with new PartitionHandler where extractKey method fail due to missing key (assert with message "Partition key cannot be null").
 
The question is, How can we maintain the previous behavior with the same settings or with less changes. How we can keep not using a key and ensure messages goes to partitions in round robin strategy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The count is now used in the decision.

```
public boolean isPartitioned() {
    return this.partitionCount > 1 || this.partitionKeyExpression != null
            || this.partitionKeyExtractorName != null || this.partitionKeyExtractorClass != null;
}
```

I think this is wrong [#1531](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/1531).

As a work around, don't set the stream `producer.partitionCount` if you want to use native kafka partitioning (and the topic already exists).

Comment: thanks, it will solve our issue until the next version released.